# How much XP does a character with LA start with in D&D 3.5e?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, experience-points, character-advancement, character-levels

I understand that a newly minted drow (LA +2) sorcerer will have an ECL of 3, meaning that for XP purposes he is treated as being level 3. Thus he will require a total of 6,000 XP to gain his second level of sorcerer, just as a human sorcerer would require a total of 6,000 XP to advance from level 3 to level 4. (Please correct me if this is not the case.)

My question is, would the drow character begin play with 3,000 XP, the minimum required for a 3rd-level character, or would he begin with 0 XP as normal characters do? In other words, how much of an XP "debt" does LA +2 represent?

Comment: As an aside: If rest of the party is starting at level 1 with 0 xp, the ECL of 3 is telling you that this is not really a valid starting character. There are a couple of ways around that, but with your relatively low ECL, one simple fix *would* be to start with 0xp (or, if you like, a 3000xp "debt') so you are in sync with the rest of the group. If the whole team is starting at level 3, then your accepted answer by Momonga-sama is all you need.

Comment: @NeilSlater note that if your ECL3 character starts with 0 xp, then because he will earn less xp per encounter than his CL1 allies, he will actually be the last one to hit ECL4.

Comment: @DanHenderson: Maybe true in general for higher ECLs, but IIRC there is no difference between xp rewards granted at levels 1 to 3. This calculator for instance shows no difference  however you structure an encounter vs PC team of 1st, 2nd, 3rd level characters, they all get same xp: http://www.d20srd.org/extras/d20encountercalculator/

Comment: Oh, that's right, I forgot that the difference didn't apply until level 4. D'oh!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The character will begin with 3000 EXP

[SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/improvingMonsters.htm)

> To determine the effective character level (ECL) of a monster character, add its level adjustment to its racial Hit Dice and character class levels. **The monster is considered to have experience points equal to the minimum needed to be a character of its ECL**.

Comment: Ah! That's simple enough. I must have overlooked that line a dozen times. Thank you!